# Is there a revokable, standalone Windows security object that can't be regenerated?

Tags: windows, security

Is there some token or other identifier available in Windows that satisfies the following criteria, some kind of GUID in a central security repository?

- It is created through a program call from C/C++ (not MFC)
- It is unique on that system
- It persists through reboots
- Once revoked, the identifier cannot be regenerated on that system, including through user editing of the registry
- It works on a totally standalone system with no network available as well as on networked systems
- It is available from Windows 7 onwards (XP support preferred but not mandatory)
- It has a low chance of collision on other systems if the identifier was copied
- Some representation of the value could be written to a file so on later running a program can tell if it is still enabled (seems trivial but covering my bases for any truly exotic in-memory-only structures).

thanks

Comment: No.  I don't think so.  Only truly secure gadget I've run across was an iButton with a built-in RTC and Java Machine.  Now THAT was a secure dongle.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a local user account and use it's SID. Even if a new account is created with the same username later, the SID will be different.

But that assumes that you're allowed to create user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Your last point is trivially true given the third point. Files are the only thing which persist after reboot. But that same logic means your 4th point is unachievable. Just revert the involved files to the original point. Even the registry is no magic, it's just another file. (Especially in the absence of a network)

Comment: Yes files are the only thing that persist through reboots but there's a difference between an accessible file out in user space and an entry buried deep in some tightly-managed system security database, which is what I'm hoping to find.